# Refactor multiple condition statements in map function

Tags: javascript, react.js, jsx

I would love some help or some directions with refactoring this block of code. It perfectly works but it kind of looks ugly ;). It was messier but I tried to make it DRY-er.

```
  const uploadedFiles = images.map((item, index) => {
  if (images.length < 2) {
    if (item.file.name.match(/.(gif)$/i)) {
      return (
        <ImageGif
          key= {index}
          src= {item.blobUrl}
          onClose={this.props.removeImage}
        />
      );
    }

    return (<ImageContainer
      src={item.blobUrl}
      key={index}
      id={index}
      onClose={this.props.removeImage}
    />);
  }

  if (images.length >= 2) {
    if (MAX_SIZE === index + 1) {
      return (<ImageContainer
          src={item.blobUrl}
          key={index}
          id={index}
          onClose={this.props.removeImage}
          hiddenImages={hiddenImages}
        />);
    }
    if (MAX_SIZE !== index + 1) {
      return (<ImageContainer
          src={item.blobUrl}
          key={index}
          id={index}
          onClose={this.props.removeImage}
        />);
    }
  }

  return null;
});
```

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Please read [ask] to understand how to title your question, and then edit your question to change the title accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ES2017 object spread:

```
const uploadedFiles = images.map((item, index) => {
  const props = {
    key: index,
    src: item.blobUrl,
    onClose: this.props.removeImage,
  };

  const isSingleGif = images.length === 1 && /\.gif$/i.test(item.file.name);
  if (isSingleGif) {
    return (<ImageGif {...props} />);
  }

  const isLastOfVisible = index === MAX_SIZE - 1 && index > 0;
  return (<ImageContainer
    id={index}
    {...props}
    {...isLastOfVisible && {hiddenImages}}
  />);
});
```

Not tested.

Notes:

- `images.length < 2` was misleading and confusing. The `.map` callback runs only when there are some elements so `0` is not possible. Simply compare with `1`.
- `images.length >= 2` is superfluous and thus confusing: the previous check ensured this is always the case.
- `MAX_SIZE === index + 1` this yoda style obfuscates the actual goal, which is to determine whether the element is the last in the range.
- `MAX_SIZE !== index + 1` is superfluous and thus confusing: the previous check ensured this is always the case.
- `/.(gif)$/i` incorrectly allowed any character before `gif`. The dot should be escaped. Also, no need for the slower `.match` if you don't use the captured strings. Use `.test`

Comment: Object spreading correctly handles `0`, `false`, `null`, `undefined` - just like Object.assign.